# How to check HDD health beyond S.M.A.R.T. in Linux CLI?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, arch-linux

I have a headless home server that I control exclusively via SSH.
It runs an up-to-date version of Arch Linux (kernel 5.4.15). For a storage, I have an LVM volume group spanning across 2 physical HDDs, 2TB each, same make, same model, different age. I also may be expanding the storage in the near future.

I'm looking for an utility to periodically test their health, and I do not trust S.M.A.R.T., as most of the time when it fails, it's already too late. Therefore, `smartctl`, as well as any utility that exclusively relies on it, doesn't fit my needs. I'm looking for something like [HDDScan](https://hddscan.com/) or [Victoria](https://victoria.en.lo4d.com/windows) but for Linux CLI rather than Windows GUI.

Considering the above, the utility I'm looking for should:

- Have a Linux version
- Either not have a GUI or have it optional, with also an option to work from command line
- Not rely on S.M.A.R.T., but instead make its own measurements of read/write speed for each block of the device it's checking

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there's the badblocks utility.

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/badblocks

> This can be done in a destructive write-mode that effectively wipes
>   the device (do backup!) or in non-destructive read-write (backup
>   advisable as well!) and read-only modes.

The non-destructive test:

```
# badblocks -nsv /dev/device

Checking for bad blocks in non-destructive read-write mode
From block 0 to 488386583
Checking for bad blocks (non-destructive read-write test)
Testing with random pattern: done                                                 
Pass completed, 0 bad blocks found. (0/0/0 errors)

The -n option signifies a non-destructive read-write test.
```

This is a **slow** test; it will basically write twice your disk size during the check. I would not run this too often. Make sure to check the block size of your disk and pass it with  `-b 4096` ( Also I haven't used this utility in ages so read the wiki carefully before you try )

Comment: The bad thing about badblocks is that it does not stress the HDD head with random reads.